# Instagram Location: Who can see?

Tags: privacy, instagram

Can someone see my location on Instagram, if I only like pictures of the person I am following, but haven't posted any pictures?

Answer (score 1):

No, if you have not added your location in your profile and have not added any picture or video with location, no one can see your location.

For more details read this: [Does Instagram use background location?](https://help.instagram.com/701414446593937)

> Instagram does not collect background location on Android or iOS (including iOS 8). Instagram only gets your location when you’re using the app, such as when you’re trying to [add a location](https://help.instagram.com/236245819849257) to your post.